# angular6-social-login isn't working with me

Tags: angular9

**this is my app.module**

```
 import { SocialLoginModule, AuthServiceConfig, GoogleLoginProvider } from 'angular-6-social-login';
    const config = new AuthServiceConfig([{
id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
provider: new GoogleLoginProvider("CLIENTID")}]);

export function provideConfig() {
  return config;
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    RestaurantComponent,
    FilterPipe,
    LoginComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
NgbModule,
SocialLoginModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
 FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [{provide: AuthServiceConfig,useFactory: provideConfig
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**this is my app component**

```
import { AuthService,GoogleLoginProvider, SocialUser } from 'angular-6-social-login';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  signinForm: FormGroup;
  user: SocialUser;
  loggedIn: boolean;  


  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.loggedIn = (user != null);//to be used in the html component
      console.log(this.user);

    });
  }
  signInWithGoogle(): void {
    this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
    console.log("iddd"+GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }
  signOut(): void {
    this.authService.signOut();
  }
```

**this is my error**

ERROR in node_modules/angular-6-social-login/auth.module.d.ts:1:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (angular-6-social-login) which declares SocialLoginModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

1 export declare class SocialLoginModule {

Comment: Hope this can help you:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8qDtOx1jIc